# How to build an .so binary for a device with a 64-bit CPU?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, 64-bit, shared-libraries

As you know, Android L will support devices (mobile phones) based on a 64-bit target CPU (ARM).

So I am preparing for native code binaries (`.so` file extension) for that kind of 64-bit Android phone.

How can I build an `.so` binary for a 64-bit target with Android NDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667086/how-to-build-an-so-binary-for-a-device-with-a-64-bit-cpu#new-answer

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigation, setting the following variable fixes my question in Application.mk.

APP_ABI := arm64-v8a

Coould anyone confirm my answer ?

Thanks.

Comment: if you do this, you'll compile only for the arm64-v8a architecture. You should specify explicitly the list of architectures you want to support inside APP_ABI. 64bit archs right now are *arm64-v8a* *x86_64* and *mips64*

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the latest version of the NDK (right now it's r10c).

If you set `APP_ABI := all` inside *Application.mk*, your native library will be compiled for all the supported architectures, including the 64bit ones.

You can also specify a list of the architectures you want to compile against, for example:

`APP_ABI := x86 armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

You can all the architectures you want to compile against, for example:

```
APP_ABI := all
```